# Pokemon go keeps restarting

Tags: pokemon-go

Since a while, I cant log in with the google account on pokemon go.
If I select google, the game gives a black loading screen, en than you see the 'Niantic' logo and it restarts. This happens every time I select google, the trainer club account however still works. I already deleted the game and reïnstalled, cleared cach, but nothing works. I have got a Samsung galaxy S7, but on my samsung galaxy S4 it still works with google and trainer account. Does anybody knows a answer??

Comment: The standard troubleshooting first step is uninstalling/reinstalling the game. Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, over 10 times already, but it doesnt work

Comment: Is your Samsung Galaxy S7 rooted? Also, make sure you have Mock Location disabled. Servers seem to be a bit rocky today, it may have a role in this issue. You can check http://ispokemongodownornot.com to see the current status.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe uninstalling/reinstalling isn't correctly deleting all the cache files - go into app settings, find Pokemon Go (while it is installed) and force close it. Then clear its cache and data, and try again.

If you are installing from some APK website (if the game isn't officially available in your area yet), perhaps try downloading another copy of the game from somewhere else.

EDIT: Also, perhaps just make sure your S4 isn't currently running PokeGo while you try to log in on your S7. There could be some kind of protection against that.